# Workaround stalling chrome when xdebug session cookie set?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, xdebug

This is a bit specific situation, I wonder if anyone else has encountered the following:

Chrome starts stalling when xdebug session cookie is set. The cookie might be leftover from previous debugging, all requests (ajax or "normal") slow down (15 seconds to 2 minutes before starting to receive), when debugging is not in use. I use PHPStorm for debugging, but it makes no difference if phpstorm is running or not when the stalling takes place.

EDIT: Steps to reproduce the stalling:

1. Open php storm project and start debugging (index.php in my case)
2. Set some breakpoints and refresh the page in chrome
3. Run over the breakpoints until finished
4. Click "stop debugging" on php storm
5. Refresh the page in chrome (and this is where the stalling starts)

Once the stalling starts, the chrome tab will become a bit unresponsive, but it can be closed.

Manually removing the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie (between steps 4 and 5) fixes the problem, but I'd really like a working solution. One solution might be switching to other browsers as I have not experienced such slowdown on IE or FF, but I really like working with chrome.

EDIT: I also managed to create a bookmarklet that deletes the cookie, but even that solution does not satisfy me in this situation, as I must remember to click the bookmarklet before trying to navigate any further, otherwise chrome will stall once again.

The biggest annoyance is that I don't understand WHERE the stalling takes place, on the chrome (client) side or at the server side. I am suspecting chrome as this does not happen with other browsers.

<s>I am placing a bounty on this, I want to know if there is something XDEBUG-related in chrome, and if either party (xdebug or chrome/chromium) can do anything about this bug.</s>

The bounty on this question has ended, and there are no answers to award it to.

Comment: DId you ever find out a solution? I'm facing exactly the same problem..

Comment: No, and this comes up every now and then. As a workaround, you can use a bookmarklet that deletes the cookie. I can post one here tomorrow, as I got one at my work computer.

Comment: I'm using this chrome extensions, which enables/disables the debug cookie. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en.  However it's still a bit painful to have to do this....

Comment: @David Yes, I am aware of that extension, but it is basically the same as the bookmarklets that enable/disable those cookies.

Comment: could you tell me please what version of xdebug you are using?

Comment: @PawelDubiel I try to remember to check tomorrow when I return to work..

Comment: @PawelDubiel Forgot earlier, and was on vacation for a week, but now I remembered to check the version: `xdebug 2.4.0RC3`