# Why do host file entries ending in .local result in slow content download?

Tags: php, laravel, dns, localhost, local

I just fixed a problem but do not exactly understand why the solution works.

**Setting:**

- Windows 10
- Laravel 7.0
- PHP built in server (via `php artisan serve --port=80`)
- Hosts file with entry `127.0.0.1 something.local`

**Problem:**

Making a web page request to http://something.local in the browser took very long to load. Upon inspection in chrome dev tools I found out that it is not the server but the actual content download.
Although we are talking about ~7MB to download a download time of >10sec seemed insane to me.

**Solution** *that I do not really understand* **:**

Changing the hosts file entry to `127.0.0.1 something.habibi` fixed it for me.

Why does it take so long to download a web page if I use an entry ending in .local in my hosts file?

**Thoughts:**

.local is not a top level domain but a special-use domain. It seems to me that because of this the request to a url ending in .local might not stay on my machine but goes through my wlan/router somehow and thus takes longer.

But this is as far as I got. It would be nice if someone can make better sense of this behaviour.

Comment: You might have a look at this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/607536

Comment: Thx but this is the post where I got the idea from to change the hosts entry at the first place. (Should have included that link). 
Meanwhile I know the culprit. It has nothing to do with the hosts entry but with the Xdebug helper extension from chrome.

Comment: As your solution is a new one, you also might post as an answer in the linked post, so other users might benefit from it. I personally, had the same problem, and did not have the Xdebug extension installed.

Comment: This is purely a guess, but do you have IPv6 setup?  I've seen this kind of thing when binding to IPv4 only and the browser defaulting to IPv6.  Something like `php artisan serve --host=::1 --port=80` or `php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=80` may help.  Paste the content of your hosts file.

Comment: The first one (--host::1) fails and gives me a `Laravel development server started: http://::1:80
\ Invalid address: ::1:80`. The second one (--host=127.0.0.1) behaves the same as before (long load time if extension is enabled). I'm not sure how I could dig deeper into the IPv6 vs IPv4 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can not make the special behavior of a special-use domain any clearer to you as this is not my forte at all.

**But:**
Do you - by any chance - have a chrome extension called "Xdebug helper" installed?

If this chrome extension would be the actual cause of your problem than your solution makes sense: changing the url in the browser has the effect that the Xdebug helper extension does not debug this new url you just put in.

Therefore you might think that your problem is caused by the different ending (switching from ".local" to ".habibi") but in reality it is just this chrome extension that gets disabled for the new url.

So long story short: your question is not reproducible and thus can't really be answered.

*By the way: Others seem to have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207635/workaround-stalling-chrome-when-xdebug-session-cookie-set).*

Comment: It was indeed the chrome plugin. Thanks for _really_ solving the issue. I'll get to those special-use domains later somewhere else as this was not the problem at all here.

Comment: .habibi - worked like a diamond in the sky! +1 for the new first level domain on all my local projects. Life refresher.